# XAML can't find a class from different assembly

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a class `ThumbModelPPT` which is defined in different assembly, which I reference in XAML as following:

```
mlns:thumbModel="clr-namespace:MSBusinessLogicPack.ImporterLogic;assembly=MSBusinessLogicPack.ImporterLogic"
```

which I then use it as a template for ListView item:

```
<ListView.Resources>
       <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type thumbModel:ThumbModelPPT}">
           ...............
       </DataTemplate>
 </ListView.Resources>
```

However, I get a compilation error saying that both, namespace and model class can not be found, though both are referenced properly. Before I moved the model class to different assembly, it worked fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you share the exact error?

Comment: Is the referenced class public?

Comment: Yes it is.......

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  The type reference cannot find a public type named 'ThumbModelPPT'. Line 669 Position 80. Importer C:\REPO\Show\Importer\Views\ViewImportPreview.xaml 669

Comment: does the completion work in visual when you type <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type thumbModel:   - if not xmlns is wrong;

Comment: Assuming that you wrote xmlns in the code and that the namespace and the assembly have the same name, the only thing I can think of is restarting the IDE. XAML tends to get all sad like that.

Comment: All you need to do is to remove the reference in your solution NOT XAML and then add it again and it will work.